# How to allow HTML file to read javascript global variable with required node library puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, global-variables, puppeteer

Okay so I'm making a webscraper and I'm simply trying to pass the **temp1** and **temp2** variables over to an html file to display it on a webpage but it won't let me. I've spent last 2 hours browsing stackoverflow and other forums for a solution and I can't.

I have been able to deduce that my first line `require('puppeteer');` is messing up my variables and not allowing my html file to read it. The problem is me not knowing how to fix it.

My code works otherwise.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

var soonestDate = 0; 
var fastestCouch, temp1, temp2;
var temp = [];
async function scrapeProduct() {
    const urls = [
        "https://www.thebrick.com/products/gena-2-piece-linen-look-fabric-right-facing-sectional-charcoal",
        "https://www.thebrick.com/products/gena-2-piece-linen-look-fabric-right-facing-sectional-midnight",
        "https://www.thebrick.com/products/winny-5-piece-linen-look-fabric-modular-sectional-with-ottoman-grey",
        "https://www.thebrick.com/products/winny-5-piece-linen-look-fabric-modular-sectional-with-ottoman-beige"
    ];

    const names = [
        'Gena Charcoal',
        'Gena Blue',
        'Winny Grey',
        'Winny Beige'
    ];
    
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true
    });
    for (i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        const url = urls[i];
        const promise = page.waitForNavigation({
            waitUntil: 'networkidle2'
        });
        await page.goto(`${url}`);
        await promise;
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        const productPrice = (await page.$x('//*[@id="productPrice"]/span[1]'))[0];
        const deliveryDate = (await page.$x('//*[@id="delivery-messaging"]/div/span[1]/span[2]'))[0];

        const bgPrice = await page.evaluate(el => {
            return el.textContent;
        }, productPrice);
    
        const bgDeliveryDate = await page.evaluate(el => {
            return el.textContent;
        }, deliveryDate);
        // campare soonest delivery time
        if (soonestDate == 0){
            soonestDate = bgDeliveryDate;
            soonestDateNumber = Date.parse(soonestDate);
            fastestCouch = names[i];
        }
        else if (Date.parse(bgDeliveryDate) < soonestDateNumber) {
            soonestDate = bgDeliveryDate;
            soonestDateNumber = Date.parse(soonestDate);
            fastestCouch = names[i];
        }
        temp[i] = (`${names[i]}
Price: ${bgPrice}
Delivery date: ${bgDeliveryDate}
`);

console.log(temp[i]);
    if (i==3){
        temp2 = (`\n\n\nSoonest Delivery Date is: ${soonestDate} for ${fastestCouch}`)
        console.log(temp2);
        }
    }
    await browser.close();
}

scrapeProduct();


// setInterval(scrapeProduct, 60 * 1000);
```

Still learning JS, please go easy on me. I find diving into difficult stuff helps me learn the fastest.

Comment: Could you share one of the URLs this is supposed to work on? It would make it easier to find a solution.

Comment: @ArbiDaci, It is not clear what you intend to do. What does "pass variables over to an html file to display it on a webpage" mean? You want to scrape the page or update its content?

Comment: @yeniv by “pass variables” I mean that usually you can do write a JS program and read the variable (if it’s global) in the HTML file (such as document.write();). I want to read the variables, more specifically temp1 and temp2 and display it in my website. I have it working with nodemailer to send me a email with details every hour or so but I want it on my localhost instead displayed and styled on a webpage.

Comment: @GiovanniRago, i'll update my code now with URLs